# Logstash Failing to Connect to Elasticsearch Cluster

Tags: logstash, elasticsearch, logstash-forwarder

When I have my elasticsearch.yml file as:

```
cluster.name: elasticsearch-sam-dev
node.name: Wolverine
```

My logstash output config as:

```
output {
    elasticsearch {
    cluster => "elasticsearch-sam-dev"
    host => localhost
 }
   stdout { codec => rubydebug }
}
```

It fails to connect to the cluster and cannot figure out why. When I comment out the lines cluster in the logstash config and the elasticsearch.yml file it works.

The error I get:

Logstash error - not fully copied as cannot copy and paste from dev environment :(

```
org.elasticsearch.discovery.zend.ping.unicast.UnicastZenPing$4 handlException
WARNING: [logstash-mymachine] failed to send ping to [[
```

Logstash Forwarder Error:

```
Connecting to [127.0.0.1]:5000 (127.0.0.1)
Failed to tls handshake with 127.0.0.1 read tcp 127.0.0.1:5000: i/o timeout
```

Now when I restart the logstash, logstash-forwarder, elasticsearch without the clustername everything magically works, logstash-forwarder processes 'x' number of events and logstash detects the node Wolverine. I cannot figure out why the cluster name is causing an issue. Has someone else had the same problem and managed to resolve it?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I resolved the issue appears that in my logstash output config I need to provide a port number, so my final config looks like below, not sure why I need to provide a port as assumed it will pick up the default which is 9300, but it worked.

```
output {
  elasticsearch {
  cluster => "elasticsearch-sam-dev"
  host => localhost
  port => "9300"
 }
   stdout { codec => rubydebug }
}
```